# xlib, remove delay when holding down a key

Tags: x11, xlib

I've just created a simple demo in opengl that involves movement and rotation of the camera. The problem is in the controls. There is a delay between the first time and second time that the keypress is registered when I am holding down the key. After that there is no delay between the times the keypress is registered. I'm using `XCheckMaskEvent()` to get the keypress events (the function returns automatically if their are no events in the queue). It is exactly like the pause in a word processor when holding down a key like the "a" key. Does anyone know how to eliminate this pause?

My `XCheckMaskEvent()` function looks like:

```
XCheckMaskEvent(display, ExposureMask | KeyPressMask, &report);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'xset` can be used to set the rate and delay for repeating keypress events for a held-down key:

http://www.x.org/archive/current/doc/man/man1/xset.1.xhtml

Example here:

http://linuxforcynics.com/how-to/set-keyboard-repeat-delay-and-rate